# Can't delete RDS on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to delete an RDS (MySQL) on AWS, but the "DELETE" button keeps greyed out even after I write "delete" in the confirmation field:

[image]

Comment: It's "delete me", not "delete".

Answer (score 29):

It should be `delete me` not only `delete`. write **delete me** and it should work.

Comment: Ouch! I really didn't process that "me"! Thanks!

Comment: Same here. AWS playing mind games

Comment: should - but delete me doesn't work now. need to select snapshot and then - remove it  :D